# Yii2 Error Exception When Gridview Filter Returns Only ONE Row

Tags: sql, filter, yii2

I have this Gridview like this:

[image: Gridview With Group By and Sum]

But whenever I use the filter and the expected result is **only ONE ROW**, it shows me this error:

***Trying to access array offset on value of type null***

This is the code in Search Model:

```
public function searchproduksi($params) {
    $query = Entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan::find()
            ->where('statusnya <> 0')
            ->select(['entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan.kode_satuan',
                'entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan.tahun',
                'entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan.triwulan',
                'entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan.kodebulan',
                'entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan.kode_kabupaten',
                'entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan.kode_komoditas',
                'entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan.statusnya',
                'kabupaten.nama_kabupaten as wilayah',
                //'entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan.banyak_satuan',
                'sum(banyak_satuan) AS banyak_satuan'
            ])
            ->groupBy(['tahun', 
                'triwulan',
                'kodebulan',
                'entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan.kode_komoditas', 
                'entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan.kode_satuan'])
    ;

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $query->joinWith(['regencyrel', 'district', 'commodity', 'unit']);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => ['tahun' => SORT_ASC, 'triwulan' => SORT_ASC, 'kodebulan' => SORT_ASC, 'kode_komoditas' => SORT_ASC,]]
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id_sampel' => $this->id_sampel,
        'entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan.triwulan' => $this->triwulan,
        'banyak_satuan' => $this->banyak_satuan,
        ...
        'entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan.kodebulan' => $this->kodebulan,
        'target' => $this->target,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'kode_perusahaan', $this->kode_perusahaan])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tahun', $this->tahun])
            ...
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'accessToken', $this->accessToken]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

The filter uses attributes ***tahun, triwulan,*** and **_kodebulan**_.

The expected SQL syntax from the code above is:

```
SELECT `entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`kode_satuan`, `entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`tahun`, `entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`triwulan`, `entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`kodebulan`, `entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`kode_kabupaten`, `entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`kode_komoditas`, `entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`statusnya`, `kabupaten`.`nama_kabupaten` AS `wilayah`, sum(banyak_satuan) AS `banyak_satuan` FROM `entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan` LEFT JOIN `perusahaan` ON `entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`kode_perusahaan` = `perusahaan`.`username` LEFT JOIN `kabupaten` ON `perusahaan`.`kode_kabupaten` = `kabupaten`.`kode_kabupaten` LEFT JOIN `kecamatan` ON `entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`id_kecamatan` = `kecamatan`.`id_kecamatan` LEFT JOIN `komoditas` ON `entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`kode_komoditas` = `komoditas`.`kode_komoditas` LEFT JOIN `satuan` ON `entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`kode_satuan` = `satuan`.`kode_satuan` WHERE (statusnya <> 0) AND ((`entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`triwulan`='2') AND (`entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`kodebulan`='5')) AND (`tahun` LIKE '%2020%') GROUP BY `tahun`, `triwulan`, `kodebulan`, `entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`kode_komoditas`, `entrisampelbulanantanpaduplicateplusperusahaan`.`kode_satuan` ORDER BY `tahun`, `triwulan`, `kodebulan`, `kode_komoditas` LIMIT 20
```

I run it in PhpMyAdmin and it gives one row.

When the result of the filter returns more than one row (I run it in PhpMyAdmin too, just in case, and it gives more than one row), it works just fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try finding the generated SQL in the debug panel and see if it is different to what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SOLUTION***

I don't know why but when I remove the join `regencyrel` which is a join via another join, it works wonders.

```
$query->joinWith(['commodity', 'unit']);
```